# Differentiated access control. Best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, access-control

I'm currently working on a hobby project in Rails, and stumbled upon a what I will think is a common problem in Rails. I've been through a couple of chapters plus and a Lynda tutorial, but I haven't found any best practices for this problem. Maybe the online community can help me.

In my application.html.erb I have added the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
  <title>SioMeny</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>SiO Menysystem</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="site_menu">
       <%= render :partial => "shared/admin_menu" if admin_logged_in? %>
       <%= render :partial => "shared/user_menu" if logged_in? %>
       <%= render :partial => "shared/site_menu" %>
    </div><!-- div#site_menu -->
   <div id="main">
      <%= render :partial => "shared/flash", :locals => {:flash => flash} unless flash.nil? %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div><!-- div#wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

My problem starts in the #site_menu and in the loading of the different partials. What I try to achieve here is a menu that is expanding according to the privileges a user may have. The logged_in? and the admin_logged_in? Is located in the application_controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


  def login_required
    unless logged_in?
     flash[:notice] = "Du må være logget inn for å se denne siden"
     redirect_to :controller => "user", :action => "login"
   end
 end

   def admin_required
   unless admin_logged_in?
     flash[:notice] = "Du må være logget inn som administrator for å se denne siden"
     redirect_to :controller => "user", :action => "login"
   end
 end



  def logged_in? 
    if session[:user_id]
     return true
   end
    return false
 end

  def admin_logged_in? 
   if logged_in?
      user = User.find_by_id[:user_id]
     if user.is_admin?
       return true
     end
   end
   return false
  end


end
```

At this point I get an error:

```
ArgumentError in Site#index

Showing /Users/ola/Documents/Coding/SioMeny/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #15):

12:       <h1>SiO Menysystem</h1>
13:     </header>
14:     <div id="site_menu">
15:       <%= render :partial => "shared/admin_menu" if admin_logged_in? %>
16:       <%= render :partial => "shared/user_menu" if logged_in? %>
17:       <%= render :partial => "shared/site_menu" %>
18:     </div><!-- div#site_menu -->
Rails.root: /Users/ola/Documents/Coding/SioMeny
```

Any help is very welcome! I have also tried to get both the logged_in functions to set an instance variable which of type Boolean which is checked in the view, this worked, but not all the time since they were depending on when they were set. I also tried to make similar methods in a helper and call them from the view, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this line in admin_logged_in?

```
user = User.find_by_id[:user_id]
```

using the brackets at the end of find_by_id, doesn't pass the symbol in as a parameter, it just directly calls find_by_id with no parameters. And find_by_id expects a parameter. Assuming you had a :user_id available in your params hash, you could do something like this instead:

```
user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting this error. It took me a long time and I didnt even find it :) By the way, do you know any best practices for dealing with more user types in rails?

Comment: No problem. :) Seems like the popular way to handle varying permissions is through the use of roles. I'd take a look at the following gems, they might point you in the right direction: easy_roles, devise, and cancan (or canable, or authority).